# Setting colors for histogram with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I already plot bar chart with two colors and you can see how is look like chart below:

[image]

I made this with ggplot2 package where for colors I used this lines of code

```
 scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
 scale_color_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

So far so good but now I want to plot histogram on different data set but with same colors. In order to do this I used this lines of code:

```
Plot_2019<- DISTRBUTIONS_2019 + geom_histogram(aes(color = gender, fill = gender),alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
            labs(
              x = "Annual sales (US)",
              y = "Count",
              title = " ",
              subtitle = " "
            )+
          scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
          scale_color_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+
            theme_light()
```

Output from this code is like pic below, although I used same command for colors, so can any body help me how to make this chart with same colors like first chart ?

[image]

Comment: When I make a bar plot with those two colors, I get the two colors that you get in the histogram, not the two colors that are in the bar plot above.

Comment: I guess `theme_light()` overrides the colours.

Answer (score 1):

These are your colors:

```r
scales::show_col(c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

[image]