# Manually setting colors in combined histogram in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have these combined histograms:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rbind(data.frame(data = rnorm(500, -1, 1), group = 'First'),
           data.frame(data = rnorm(500, 1, 1), group = 'Second'))
ggplot(x, aes(data, fill=group)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, aes(y=(100*..count..)/sum(..count..)), color='black', position='identity')
```

In the plot, I would like to manually color the first group as red and the second group as green. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65549073/setting-colors-for-histogram-with-ggplot2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092642/colored-histogram-with-ggplot2), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016316/how-to-manually-fill-colors-in-a-ggplot2-histogram), but these did not answer my question.

Comment: Add `+ scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green'))` to your plot

Comment: I suggest you used a named vector, perhaps `values=c(First="red", Second="green")`, as it removes ambiguity. While not a factor here, realize that the order that you provide and the order ggplot uses internally may not be the same (alphabetic sorting versus factors, for instance); if you do not name them, then it is possible that the colors are assigned to the incorrect groups. This might be obviously wrong in some circumstances but seems an unnecessary risk. @AllanCameron

Comment: What exactly did you try to change the colors that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to add/consider here:

1. ggplot2 is recommending `after_stat(.)` instead of `..count..`;
2. Add `color=group` *inside* your `aes(..)` call, and you may also want `fill=` (which works here so long as you keep `alpha=0.5`; and
3. Use a named vector of colors in a call to `scale_*_manual`.

First, using `after_stat(count)` and `color=group` only:

```r
ggplot(x, aes(data, fill=group)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5,
    aes(y=(100*after_stat(count))/sum(after_stat(count)), color=group, fill=group),
    position='identity') +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(First="red", Second="green"))
```

[image: ggplot with color aesthetic by group]

Same thing but including `fill=` and `scale_fill_manual` (and pre-defining the named vector of colors):

```r
mycolors <- c(First="red", Second="green")
ggplot(x, aes(data, fill=group)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5,
    aes(y=(100*after_stat(count))/sum(after_stat(count)), color=group, fill=group),
    position='identity') +
  scale_color_manual(values=mycolors) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=mycolors)
```

[image: ggplot with color and fill aesthetics by group]